# Java simple login system using a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to learn how loops work, here's a very simple login system I wrote. There seems to be an error with this code though

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
static String password, loginPass, username, loginUser;
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

static boolean login = true;
static boolean checkvalid = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a desired username: \n");
    username = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter a desired password: \n");
    password = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Thank you, please log in.\n");
    while (login) {
        checkvalid = false;
        System.out.println(" ------------------ \n" + "Username: \n");
        loginUser = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Password: \n");
        loginPass = sc.nextLine();

        if (loginUser.equals(password) && (loginPass.equals(username))) {
            checkvalid = true;
        } else {
            checkvalid = false;
        }
    }
    for (;;){
        if (checkvalid = true){
            login = false;
            System.out.println("You have logged in.");

        }else if (checkvalid = false){
            System.out.println("Incorrect username or password");
            login = true;
        }
    }
}

}
```

It repeatedly asks for the "desired login credentials" that I entered before. Please help me resolve this problem, thank you!)

Comment: `if (checkvalid = true){` => `if (checkvalid == true){`. Same with `= false`, change the `=` to `==`.

Comment: You forgot to break out of the loop when you set checkvalid true

Comment: Ok there is a syntax error then how you have run it

Comment: @AntonH true, but that isn't his problem because his program will never get there

Comment: Instead of checkvalid = true make it login = true because your while loop will never break out and your code will not reach the for loop any more.

Comment: @ajb Which is why I put it as a comment, not an answer. Also because I didn't look further, but ignore that :)

Comment: I'm wondering how you will be getting outside that while loop, because no where inside that loop value of **login** is changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're stuck inside the first loop forever because you never change the value of login. The second loop is also not necessary and you can move that code into the conditionals in your while loop. Try the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a desired username: \n");
    username = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter a desired password: \n");
    password = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Thank you, please log in.\n");
    while (login) {
        checkvalid = false;
        System.out.println(" ------------------ \n" + "Username: \n");
        loginUser = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Password: \n");
        loginPass = sc.nextLine();

        if (loginUser.equals(username) && (loginPass.equals(password))) {
            checkvalid = true;
            login = false;
            System.out.println("You have logged in.");
        } else {
            checkvalid = false;
            System.out.println("Incorrect username or password");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`while (login)` executes the body of the `while` loop until `login` is false.  The body of the while loop is the part that ends at the closing curly brace.  In your case, this is the last statement of the body:

```
    if (loginUser.equals(password) && (loginPass.equals(username))) {
        checkvalid = true;
    } else {
        checkvalid = false;
    }
```

After this `if` is performed, *the program loops back to the beginning of the while loop body*.  It never gets to the rest of the code (`for(;;)` or the code that prints "You have logged in") until `login` becomes false (or there's a `break` statement).  And you never set `login` to false inside the `while` loop.  The only place `login` is set to false is outside the `while` loop body, and as long as your program is stuck inside the while loop, it will never get there.

You probably wanted the code that sets `login` to false to be *inside* the `while` loop--not in a separate loop:

```
while (login) {
    checkvalid = false;
    System.out.println(" ------------------ \n" + "Username: \n");
    loginUser = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Password: \n");
    loginPass = sc.nextLine();

    if (loginUser.equals(password) && (loginPass.equals(username))) {
        checkvalid = true;
    } else {
        checkvalid = false;
    }
    if (checkvalid == true){
        login = false;
        System.out.println("You have logged in.");

    }else if (checkvalid == false){
        System.out.println("Incorrect username or password");
        login = true;
    }
}
```

[I've also fixed the `if (checkvalid = true)` error you made, as noted in comments.  This last could be simplified, though:

```
    if (checkvalid) {  // you never have to use "== true" to check a boolean
        login = false;
        System.out.println("You have logged in.");

    }else {  // if we get here, checkvalid has to be false, no need to test it again
        System.out.println("Incorrect username or password");
        login = true;
    }
```

There are other ways to simplify this even more, but this is enough off-topic simplification for one answer.]

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you are comparing `username` with `loginPass` and `password` with `loginUser`, may be that's what you want. I'm just suggesting you can omit the `checkvalid`. You can do something like this

```
static boolean login = false;

while (!login) {
      System.out.println(" ------------------ \n" + "Username: \n");
      loginUser = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Password: \n");
      loginPass = sc.nextLine();

      if (loginUser.equals(password) && (loginPass.equals(username))) {
          System.out.println("You have logged in.");
          login = true;
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("Incorrect username or password");
      }
}
```

Try keeping that login as false until login is success, because someone who comes after you will find it confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :D

```
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            String x = sc.nextLine();// Put the user

            while(!x.equals("John")) {                  
                System.out.println("Wrong User, try again :D"); 
                x = sc.nextLine();

            }
            sc.close();
```